# C++ Read input from STDIN at a buffered rate

Tags: c++, string, c++11, buffer, stdin

I'm taking the contents of a txt file and piping it into my application as below.

cat file.txt | ./app [args]

My problem is, the current manner in which I am processing the application is essentially taking the entire contents of 'file.txt' and storing it in STDIN.

This works fine for a file that is relatively small but will cause the application to crash / overflow if the TXT file is too large.

I'm looking for a solution which will allow me to read data from the file at a "buffered rate" such that the entire contents of the file will not be stored when the program begins.

Her is a snippet of how I am currently taking the input.

```
  std::vector<string> lines = LinesInFile(std::cin);  // Storing lines
```

Which makes use of the following function.

```
std::vector<std::string> LinesInFile(std::istream& input_file) {
  std::string text_from_input;
  std::vector<std::string> lines_from_file;

    while (std::getline(input_file, text_from_input)) {
      lines_from_file.push_back(text_from_input);
    }
return lines_from_file;
}
```

This currently works and will take the correct input. But obviously this is not productive code and runs the possibility of some larger issues.

I'd simply like to "process" the data from the TXT file and not store the entirety the contents of the file in memory.

I am currently using C++ so I'd prefer not to use older standard C functions. Honestly I'd prefer C++11 and up.

Thank you for any help in advance.

EDIT:

I wanted to clarify that I at first was storing each separate line in the vector to prcoess each line individually. I understand I could process each line as it comes in but this will still pose a potential issue in that if a file does not contain a newline char then I would still risk overflow and potential issues.

EDIT:

I understand that this is incredibly unlikely most of the time. However, that's not my concern in regards to this post.

Comment: And why don't you process the lines inside the while instead of pushing them in the array?

Comment: Well, originally what I was doing was taking each line and pushing it's data back in the vector. Once it was done separating and storing each line I would then return the vector and use the vector inside of a different process later.

Comment: Essentially I am processing each line. at this point i would think that i can process the data inline and search for a '\n' or EOF as i am processing the file. rather then splitting each line like I am right now. Part of the help I need improving my method, I'll be it a bit messy ATM.

Comment: Another potential issue, if I instead only process line by line is that if a file never has a return char. then it will essentially be one gigantic line, and I will once again run into my possible overflow problem.

Comment: stdin _is_ buffered by default.   But you wrote code to extract all of it at once and hold it in memory?  Well, don't do that then.  Process each line one at a time.  This is so strange I'm not sure I understand the question at all.  If a line does not contain a newline, there's no overflow issue, the only issue is bad_alloc.  And the correct thing to do there is print an error and quit.  Pretty straightforward actually.

Comment: That is actually something I was wondering about. I wasn't sure if it would automatically be buffered or if I had to setup a buffer.  I had read information about having to use somehting like "std::cin::sync(false)" or something to make sure the buffer was working. I really did not know that. I thought piping a file after catting it would cause the entire thing to go into the program.

Answer (score 0):

> This works fine for a file that is relatively small but will cause the
>   application to crash / overflow if the TXT file is too large.

I suspect your worry is premature.

The size of a vector on my system is about 12 bytes in the stack, regardless of how many strings or how many bytes.  Though I've not confirmed it, I think this means that the contents of your vector reside in your heap.

My machine has 4 GBytes of ram, and the same in swap (though swap would be painfully slow).  It takes a very big file to fill that much ram.

I regularly transfer the entire file into ram using a std::stringstream, as in:

```
  m_ss << sIn.rdbuf();
  if(sIn.bad())
     throw "DTB::Filter::load()  'm_ss << sIn bad after rdbuff()'";
```

And then either process it normally line-by-line out of the stringstream, or, sometimes I take short-cuts and process the entire file as a single string copied using stringstream.str()

Review your plans -- will your text files ever get larger than your ram?

---

Next consider that you build it as you now plan.

How hard will it be to change to line-by-line processing?

Using stringstream as I do, the refactoring is quite simple.  RAM is much faster than (most of) my drives, too.

Although I've not yet found a need to, it is possible to stat the file and have your code decide at run time that its size is big enough to skip the stringstream or vector temp store.

Does  1) "load container + processing line-by-line out of ram" take more time than 2) "process file line-by-line"?

I don't know.  I don't work with gigabyte text files, but I suppose I can create one, and measure it ... maybe later when I meet a real need.

Comment: You're correct in the assumption that this should almost never happen. I'm jsut concerned with a better / correct manner of doing this for best practice. I've taken it upon myself lately to really understand some of those "will probably never happen but COULD" solutions for further knowledge.

Comment: Essentially, in the event it ever DOES happen. I'd be out of luck. Or if this were to be a different scenario. I guess a better way to consider this is buffering piped input rather then jsut storing the whole thing. If in the case I'm not even working with txt files.